# Problems with joining tables sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having trouble creating an appropriate sql query for this situation. I have 1 table where CATEGORY_ID is stored.

```
p_xref
+-------------+
| CATEGORY_ID |
+-------------+
|        5005 |
+-------------+
```

This CATEGORY_ID is the parent category and it may have child category IDs. I check for this in my next table. For each CATEGORY_ID in this table there is a PARENT_CAT_ID. If there is no parent for that category, it is set at -1. My query currently looks for a match between PARENT_CAT_ID and the CATEGORY_ID in the first table.

```
category_profile
+-------------+---------------+
| CATEGORY_ID | PARENT_CAT_ID |
+-------------+---------------+
|        5028 |          5005 |
|        5005 |            -1 |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I then match this category ID with the final table in order to grab an ITEM_ID.

```
item_xref
+-------------+---------+
| CATEGORY_ID | ITEM_ID |
+-------------+---------+
|        5028 |    6767 |
+-------------+---------+
```

The problem with my current query is that it only grabs the children categories, and does not work for parent categories. I can do the opposite and match all parent categories and no child categories. Is there anyway to combine the two queries?

Query 1:Grabs child category matches only

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM promotion p 
                LEFT JOIN p_xref pcx ON p.P_ID = pcx.P_ID
                LEFT JOIN category_profile cp ON pcx.CATEGORY_ID = cp.PARENT_CAT_ID   
                LEFT JOIN item_xref icx ON cp.CATEGORY_ID = icx.CATEGORY_ID
                WHERE icx.ITEM_ID = "randomID"
```

Query 2:Grabs parent category matches only

```
                SELECT DISTINCT DATE FROM promotion p 
                LEFT JOIN p_xref pcx ON p.P_ID = pcx.P_ID 
                LEFT JOIN item_xref icx ON pcx.CATEGORY_ID = icx.CATEGORY_ID
                WHERE icx.ITEM_ID = "RandomID"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe will need to use  NOT IN  clause

Comment: Have you considered using UNION ALL?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but wouldn't your first query work if you changed the WHERE to point to cp.parent_cat_id="randomID" (querying against the parent cat rather than the cat)? Also, parent cat records would be omitted if there are no child records of that cat (per the final join). Just a couple of thoughts - perhaps I"m misunderstanding the question...

Comment: Without looking @ it in detail, you could use a view for 1/2 of the query and then rejoin the view to the second statement... This would simplify it (perhaps you're running in to outer join restrictions based on the version of SQL you're using, and this would work around that...)

Comment: The where clause is looking for ITEM_IDs that match the CATEGORY_ID. The problem with the first query is that all of the parent category IDs are not matched. I'll take a look at the other suggestions to see if they help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
LEFT JOIN category_profile cp ON pcx.CATEGORY_ID = cp.PARENT_CAT_ID
```

to this

```
JOIN category_profile cp ON pcx.CATEGORY_ID = cp.PARENT_CAT_ID   
or pcx.category_id = cp.category_id
```

Comment: demoting to a plain "JOIN" without explicit LEFT/RIGHT isn't a good idea

Comment: and why would that be?

Comment: because it may obfuscate the desired relationship of many:1 or 1:1.. explicit INNER and LEFT is always wise. oversimplifying a LEFT from OP into an INNER will likely omit necessary rows.

Comment: I didn't realize you could use OR conditions on JOIN statements! I kept my join as a LEFT JOIN though.

Answer (score 0):

I would start in reverse to get the items that are looked for regardless, then link the other way.  By using a WHERE clause the way you have it forces into an INNER join vs a LEFT join. (No list of production table columns, but assume the date is from that table)

```
select distinct 
      p.Date
   from
      item_xref ixc
         JOIN category_profile cp
            on icx.category_id = cp.category_id
            LEFT JOIN p_xref x1
               on cp.category_id = x1.category_id
               OR cp.parent_cat_id = x1.category_id
               left join promotion p
                  on x1.category_id = p.p_id
   where
      icx.item_id = "randomid"
```

Ensure an 
index on item_xref table on the Item_id
index on category_profile on category_id